# How can I get the total hour for the datetime range

Tags: mysql

How can I calculate the total hours base on my datetime range

if I have this accepted date range `2015-09-07 06:00:00` - `2015-09-11 22:00:00`

I want to get the numbers of hours each day from 06:00:00 to 22:00:00 only for the user then sum all the hours.

here is my sample data

```
+----+---------+--+---------------------+---------------------+--+
|    |         |  |                     |                     |  |
+----+---------+--+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| id | user_id |  | start_time          | end_time            |  |
| 1  | 24      |  | 2015-09-07 07:10:01 | 2015-09-07 10:20:20 |  |
| 2  | 24      |  | 2015-09-07 12:10:00 | 2015-09-07 15:00:00 |  |
| 3  | 24      |  | 2015-09-07 16:00:00 | 2015-09-07 22:20:20 |  |
| 4  | 24      |  | 2015-09-07 23:25:20 | 2015-09-08 05:00:00 |  |
+----+---------+--+---------------------+---------------------+--+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use this TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, end_time))/3600 as hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use function `TIMESTAMPDIFF` for hours:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

**Example:**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_time, end_time) 
           as `difference` FROM timeattendance WHERE user_id = 24
```

Comment: but I only accept from 06:00:00 - 22:00:00 with the date from 2015-09-07 - 2015-09-11

Comment: but how do I put the where clause I would only query from 2015-09-07 to 2015-09-11,then with in the time 06:00:00 - 22:00:00, I tried the your solution and it give the hours but the last row is still counting

Comment: the start_time of the last row is `23:25:20` it should not be counted because I only accept until 22:00:00

Comment: And what hours you want to count? The difference between start end end time?

Comment: yes the difference of start and end time. example I want to query for this date range '2015-09-07 06:00:00' to '2015-09-11 22:00:00',I want to count the hours inside that range of user = 24

Comment: what about the mins ?

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL `TIME_TO_SEC` or `TIMEDIFF` functions

```
Select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time))/3600 as hours from table
```